# Read specific information from a point of sale Mysql Database

Tags: java, mysql, database

my name is Omar, 
I have a point of sale program in windows, which i have to acquire a specific data using Java.
The point of sale uses mysql as a database, inside the database structure, it creates a database named "iT" with a lot of tables.
I want to acquire a field data named Ticketid.

The program does not install mysql.exe in :c unit, instead of that, it uses a program named mysqld.exe located in the point of sale folder in order to work with the database.
In order to see the "iTPV" database using command prompt i had to go the the specific \bin folder of the "ITPV" program and run mysqld.exe and after that run mysql.exe as mysql -u root -p in the command prompt, i apply password and after that i get in with success.
i created a java program in order to acquire the "Ticketid" field, but with no success, maybe i have an issue in the  "String myUrl".
Before apply this program i use mysqld.exe in one command prompt window and in another i apply my java program with no success and with the following result

Got an exception! 
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

The java program is like this

```
import java.sql.*;



/**
 * A Java MySQL SELECT statement example. Demonstrates the use of a SQL
 * SELECT statement against a MySQL database, called from a Java program.
 *
 *
 */
public class calculadora {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // create our mysql database connection

            String myDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

            String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3336/itpv";
            String user = "root";

            String password = "***************";

            Class.forName(myDriver);

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, user, password);
            //Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "");

            // our SQL SELECT query. 
            // if you only need a few columns, specify them by name instead of using "*"
            String query = "SELECT * FROM tickets";

            // create the java statement
            Statement st = con.createStatement();

            // execute the query, and get a java resultset
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

            // iterate through the java resultset
            while (rs.next()) {

                int TICKid = rs.getInt("TICKETID");

                // print the results
                // System.out.format("%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s\n", id, firstName, lastName, dateCreated, isAdmin, numPoints);
                System.out.format("%s\n", TICKid);
            }
            st.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that the problem is a mysql connecting issue with database, 
the password is right and the structure of the program is right too.
maybe i am not able to locate well the "String myUrl" address, is there a way inside mysql databased command prompt to acquire the correct location of String myUrl of a database?, what is the purpose of mysqld.exe?, thank you in advance, anyhelp is appreciated

Omar Torres

Comment: I replaced your password with ****** in the post for safety. If that is your real password you should definitely change it since it has been on such a public place.

Answer (score 0):

¿Estás seguro de que has cargado el controlador del sistema gestor de base de datos com.mysql.jdbc.Driver?

¿You're sure you have correctly loaded the driver of relational database management system com.mysql.jdbc.Driver?

Comment: how does the com.mysql.jdbc.driver is charged?, how can i do that using command line?

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way inside mysql databased command prompt to acquire the
>   correct location of String myUrl of a database?

No because the URL you need for Java is specific to the jdbc driver.

> what is the purpose of mysqld.exe?

It is the server process. It should run in the background when your java program needs to put something in the database or ask what is in the database it will ask this program to do it. Using a server allows multiple programs to share the same data.

**Possible Problem**

The default port for mysql is 3306 you have the port set as 3336 which might be a typo. Although the port can be reconfigured.

Comment: i changed from 3336 to 3306 and i got the same result                           Got an exception! com.mysql.jdbc.Driver,                                                    using mysql -u root -p; i can get into the database, but using the java program above i can't :(, mysql is not installed in the computer locally, the point of sale uses mysql.exe and mysqld.exe to work with databases locally, i don't know how that program do that

Comment: If mysql is not installed locally then localhost should be replaced with the hostname or IP address  of the computer running the mysql server.  You may be running mysqld locally unnecessarily. It is strange that if the database is not installed locally that you would not need -h hostname when running mysql. Also you should print the full text of the exception. As the other answer pointed out you may be missing the driver. I have added some details to this answer to check/fix this.

Comment: The point of sale has this characteristics in order to connect with its own database DRIVER(library): \TechBusiness\iTPV\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar,      DRIVER(class): com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.,     CONNECTION CHAIN: jdbc:mysql:mxj//localhost:3336/itpv?server.basedir=iTPV-d..., USER:root, access key: *****************,

Comment: i am using in my program above the connection chain data in  String myUrl , and user key, but with no success :(, what i am doing wrong in my program?, maybe it is the driver\TechBusiness\iTPV\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar, how can i load this driver in my java program???, thank you anyhelp is appreciated